# Looking for raw cell videos from a light microscope

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, cell-culture, microscopy

First off, I'm not looking for online lectures.

I am trying to find creative commons licensed videos of live cells moving around without annotation or anything extra. I would prefer a few minutes of video of tumorous somatic cultures of eukaryotes in vitro and at a few different magnifications but it doesn't really matter. I don't have a microscope or I'd just get some pond water and look at multicellular organisms. The license must be creative commons or public domain, the author must be citable, and the subject organism should be known.

Any ideas where to find such video? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website you want is [The Cell: An Image Library](http://www.cellimagelibrary.org/). They also have movies. A quick search of ['Homo sapiens tumor'](http://www.cellimagelibrary.org/images?advanced_search=Advanced+Search&k=%22Homo+sapiens%22+tumor&image_search_parms%5bbiological_process%5d=&image_search_parms%5bcell_type%5d=&image_search_parms%5bcell_line%5d=&image_search_parms%5bfoundational_model_anatomy%5d=&image_search_parms%5bcellular_component%5d=&image_search_parms%5bmolecular_function%5d=&image_search_parms%5bncbi%5d=&image_search_parms%5bitem_type_bim%5d=&image_search_parms%5bimage_mode_bim%5d=&image_search_parms%5bvisualization_methods_bim%5d=&image_search_parms%5bsource_of_contrast_bim%5d=&image_search_parms%5brelation_to_intact_cell_bim%5d=&image_search_parms%5bprocessing_history_bim%5d=&image_search_parms%5bpreparation_bim%5d=&image_search_parms%5bparameter_imaged_bim%5d=&image_search_parms%5bidentity_bim%5d=&image_search_parms%5bhuman_dev_anatomy%5d=&image_search_parms%5bhuman_disease%5d=&image_search_parms%5bmouse_gross_anatomy%5d=&image_search_parms%5bmouse_pathology%5d=&image_search_parms%5bplant_growth%5d=&image_search_parms%5bteleost_anatomy%5d=&image_search_parms%5bxenopus_anatomy%5d=&image_search_parms%5bzebrafish_anatomy%5d=) revealed several Creative Commons videos of tumor cells moving around *in vitro* with attribution and no annotation or anything else. Sometimes the site can be a bit buggy, but it's a pretty awesome resource when it works.